# Configure networking to select best route for VPN hosts

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, routing, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server and some clients that connect to it, for example:

- host1 (at location1)
- host2 (at location2)
- laptop (my travel machine)

Is it possible to configure routing in such a way that when I'm at a remote location and connect to the VPN, I can access `host1` and `host2` through the VPN connection, but when I'm at `location1` access to `host1` is direct and does not go through the VPN?  Similarly, when I'm at `location2` access to `host2` is on the local network without having to traverse the VPN and access to `host1` continues to be through the VPN?

Is there a DNS, or some naming convention, to make this possible?

Comment: Should be automatic, if the Network is properly setup. Is your VPN always on?

Comment: How do I properly setup the network to make this automatic?